# Remove BIOS flashing functionality from windows

Tags: windows-8.1, bios, flash

Is there any way to remove from windows its BIOS-flashing capability?
Like, to prevent BIOS-flashing software that run in windows overwrite the existing BIOS?

Do I need to delete a .dll file in Windows to ever prevent it from overwriting the BIOS?

Please note, however, that I would still want to flash the BIOS using a bootable external drive **but just not in Windows**.

Computer model: Dell Inspiron 3543

Please let me know if you need other details about the computer.

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just block the executable that is responsible for upgrade from running. Using a regedit script like :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
“DisallowRun”=dword:00000001
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun]
“1″=”anyapplication.exe”
“2″=”anotherapplication.exe”
```

and replacing anyapplication (and any others you need) will block that app. Keep in mind this may be a temporary solution as users can just rename it. As for dlls it is highly probable that installation will include them too so deleting one won't help with anything.